# What does this Assembly error mean? "Language type must be specified"?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I'm just starting out learning x86 Assembly with MASM32 and I made a program and ran it, but it throws the error "language type must be specified". What does this error mean? Google searches turn up nothing.

I'm sure I included all the relevant info in my program:

```
.386
model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none
<includes>
...
```

What am I missing? I have an x64 592Mhz Intel processor and I'm using MASM32 with Windows 7 Starter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised your Google searches turned up nothing. I entered the error message into Google, and found this.

From Microsoft KB article [PROC w/ Parameters Requires Language Specifier on .MODEL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75248):

> The PROC directive used with arguments requires a language specifier
>   in the .MODEL directive in the Microsoft Macro Assembler (MASM)
>   versions 5.1, 5.1a, and 6.0, and also in the Microsoft QuickAssembler
>   versions 2.01 and 2.51. The language specifier is required because it
>   determines which parameter passing convention will be used with the
>   PROC arguments.

...

> To correct the code, specify a language in the .MODEL statement. To
>   correct the following program, replace the statement ".MODEL small"
>   with ".MODEL small, language" where language is either FORTRAN,
>   PASCAL, Basic, or C.

Comment: Huh, must have not been using the right search terms. I found out the problem though: I forgot a dot before the word "model". A DOT! >:I One missing dot gave me hundreds of errors. Why did I ever want to become a programmer...